# How can I make this line work, and what's the science behind these quotation marks?

Tags: php, html, iframe, echo

I really need to get the following line working and apart from that, would love to read an article or anything of that form to finally know how to use my quotation marks properly.

[image]

```
echo '<div class="video"><iframe width="540" height="330" src="'//www.youtube.com/embed/ . $row['link']"/>'</frame>;
```

Comment: I suggest you re-read the documentation on that, it's pretty well explained

Comment: Had to use a screenshot because I also couldn't get displaying the line here to work! :(

Comment: Please post your line, not an image. The error is here : `src="//youtube/.../'. $row['title'] .'"`

Comment: The syntax highlighting here and in your screenshot is pretty clear. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for the science.

Comment: @Mario Thanks a lot! I am definitely going to read that!

Comment: @VincentDecaux Thanks it works! Looking back it was indeed, sorry! I have little PHP knowledge and a deadline in 10 minutes! Going to read the articles after the stress is over :) Thanks anyway and I will try to upvote your comment again when my reputation is higher!

Answer (score 0):

Should be good :

```
echo '<div class="video"><iframe width="540" height="330" src="//youtube.com/embed/'. $row['link'] .'"></iframe></div>';
```

But read comments, your error was pretty easy to find with highlights syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not placed properly.
Try this:

```
<?php
    $link='//www.youtube.com/embed/'. $row['link'];
?>
<div class="video">
    <iframe width="540" height="330" src="<?php echo '//www.youtube.com/embed/'. $row['link']; ?>" /></iframe>
</div>
```